# Monoprice Graphics Tablet Driver

Tags: drivers, graphics-tablet

Monoprice 10 x 6.25 inch drawing tablet
Ubuntu 18.04
2 Monitors

This hardware works as a mouse by default, and when I move the pen from one side to the other it moves from the left of screen #1, to the right of screen #2.

1. I would like to have the tablet independent of the mouse.
2. I would like to be able to constrain or map the tablet area to within a window on either screen.

How can I do this?

Thanks